# Unable to display multiple PSCustomObjects in an Array list

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.1

I have 3 folders in the same folder, with files in it; only the 3 sub-folders have anything in them.

What I'm trying to accomplish is:

1. Query the root folder to get the sub-folders within it (*this allows it to be more dynamic for me in case I want to add more*).
2. Query each folder individually, assigning all output files (*with the current loop iteration number concatenated to the name*) into a `PSCustomObject`.
3. Then, append each newly created `PSCustomObject` to my `$myArray` variable - *the name property for each object is based on the current folder name*.
4. Finally, display the *arraylist* of `PSCustomObject`'s in **Table** format.

With the expected result of:

```
subfolder1        subfolder2    subfolder3      
----------        ----------    -----------      
1: 1              4: 2          6: 3             
2: New folder     5: New folder 7: New folder    
3: New folder (2)               8: New folder (2)
```

What I currently get is just the **first** object in my array:

```
subfolder1       
----------       
1: 1             
2: New folder    
3: New folder (2)
```

...but, I can use the comma as a unary operator and it will show the other objects in the list. Same goes for tapping into the arrays intrinsic members of `.psobject` and it will show the objects there as well.

Enough back story, here's my code:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\Abraham\Desktop\test" -Directory | 
    ForEach-Object -Begin {
        $myArray = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
        $i = 0
    } -Process {
        foreach ($folder in $input)
        {
            $name = $folder.BaseName
            $myArray.Add(
                $(foreach ($file in (Get-ChildItem -Path $folder.FullName))
                {
                    $i++
                    [PSCustomObject]@{
                        $name = "{0}: {1}" -f $i,$file.Name
                    }
                }) 
            ) | Out-Null
        }
    } -End { 
        $myArray
    }
```

**Question**:
Any ideas on how to get the appended `PSCustomObject`'s be displayed in table format?

---

*What's odd is that I can use `Select-Object -First 1/2/3`, and will be able to access each object. Can also do: `$myArray.foreach{$_ | ft *}` but, it flattens it so I can no longer display the combined results as a table; any other method wasn't working for me such as piping to `Write-Output`.*

Comment: Abraham, could you edit your question and provide a mockup of what you'd like the output to look like?

Comment: @RetiredGeek, it's under "*With the expected result of:*", but I can change it if you think it needs to be a bit more clearer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, what your code is doing, is storing the contents of each folder in an `Object[]` where `$myArray[0]` are all the contents of `subFolder1`, `$myArray[1]` are all the contents of `subFolder2`, and so on. What you're missing is the part where you *merge* or *join* each element of each array into one `PSCustomObject`, like below:

```
[pscustomobject]@{
    subfolder1 = '2: New folder'
    subfolder2 = '5: New folder'
    subfolder3 = '7: New folder'
}
```

Here is my solution to that problem:

```sh
using namespace System.Collections.Generic
using namespace System.Collections

(Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\Abraham\Desktop\test" -Directory).foreach({
    begin {
        $myArray = [Dictionary[string, ArrayList]]::new()
        $i = 0
    }
    process {
        foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName)
        {
            $i++
            $file = "{0}: {1}" -f $i,$file.Name
            if($thisKey = $myArray[$_.BaseName])
            {
                $null = $thisKey.Add($file)
                continue
            }
            $null = $myArray.Add($_.BaseName, @($file))
        }
    }
    end {
        $max = $myArray.Keys.ForEach({ $myArray[$_].Count }) | Measure-Object -Maximum
        for($i = 0; $i -lt $max.Maximum; $i++)
        {
            $out = [ordered]@{}
            foreach($key in $myArray.Keys)
            {
                $out[$key] = $myArray[$key][$i]
            }
            [pscustomobject]$out
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Ahhh, I see. Very clever solution, thank you kind sir! May you never step on a wet puddle with just socks on!

Comment: @AbrahamZinala lol! Thank you Abe, same goes to you :)

Comment: @AbrahamZinala I edited my answer cause it was very poorly explained, hopefully that makes more sense

Comment: Nah man, I got what you meant. Lol honestly hit the nail on the head tho